# Does `find` support multiple `maxdepth` conditions?

Tags: find

I want to execute a `find` search with multiple `maxdepth`s, depending on the directory.

Is this possible? It seems that `-maxdepth` is "global", but I was curious if there is some workaround.

(I'm aware it's possible to execute two separate commands, but using one would be faster, and it would keep the calling code simpler)

Comment: Why not use two `find` commands?

Comment: I've considered that, but before that, I wanted to try a single run, for both performance and sorting reasons.

Comment: It would not keep the code simpler.

Comment: [FreeBSD find](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)) supports syntax like `find dir1 dir2 \( -path 'dir1/*' -depth 1 -prune \) -o \( -path 'dir2/*' -depth 2 -prune \) -o -print`

Comment: @TavianBarnes this is in fact the answer given below :-)

Comment: @Marcus Not exactly (`-depth 2` vs `-regex`)

Comment: @TavianBarnes you're right, sorrty :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can sort of emulate it using `-prune` on different matching pathnames. For example, to match `/etc` to depth 1, and `/lib` to depth 2:

```
find /etc /lib/ \
    \( -regex '/etc/[^/]*/.*'       -prune \) \
 -o \( -regex '/lib/[^/]*/[^/]*/.*' -prune \) \
 -o -print
```

You need to be careful to add the last line to print or otherwise operate on the remaining files and directories.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can’t apply different `-maxdepth` options to different parts of a series of `find` tests. Since it’s a global option, as you point out, it applies to all the tests. If you specify multiple `-maxdepth` options, the last one is taken into account and applied to the whole command.